# Determining id attribute of own Flash element from Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a Flash application written in ActionScript 3 embedded in a web page using SWFObject 2.0. After it has been loaded, the Flash application will be running in an `<object>` or `<embed>` tag with an `id` attribute.

How can I determine the value of the `id` attribute of the element from inside the Flash application?

Comment: Boyd's suggestion is a bit more direct but you may be able to take something useful away from this forum discussion about the same issue (albeit an old conversation it looks like most everything is still applicable) http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=136044

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [the `objectID` property of the `flash.external.ExternalInterface` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#objectID).

Answer (score 1):

you can use SWFObject to pass a var into the flash to tell it what the ID is when you load it.

```
swfobject.embedSWF('application.swf', '100%', '100%', null, {'id': '_id_goes_here_'}, null);
```